# htaccess : redirect an iphone user unless

Tags: iphone, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've been reading up on the syntax for constructing htaccess rules but no matter what I try, I can't get to do what I want to do.

I am aiming to redirect all iphone visitors to a subfolder on my domain, easy enough:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/iphone
RewriteRule .* http://domain.com/iphone/ [R]
```

This successfully redirects iphone users who aren't already trying to go to http://domain.com/iphone. However, I **don't want to redirect** users who are trying to go to **domain.com/app** (this url has its own redirect to an apple app store page, so i want iphone users to be redirected there as well, rather than the iphone version of my site). I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/iphone
RewriteRule .* http://domain.com/iphone/ [R]
```

I thought that the /app condition should work in parallel with the /iphone condition, but it seems iphone visitors to *domain.com/app* are still being redirected to *munch5aday.com/iphone/*.

Very grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: Bonzer. Sorted it myself. All I did was stuck "RewriteEngine off" in the htaccess file for the /app folder. Easy!

Comment: Can you mark this as closed so others know it is solved?

Answer (score 0):

Add the line `RewriteEngine off` to the directory's `.htaccess` file.

Adding answer now to avoid this question being listed as unanswered. Answer is based on questioner's comment in December 2010.